# How to GZIP compress JSON on IIS6?

Tags: json, gzip, iis-6

JSON is added to mime types, it can be accessed just fine. Everything else is getting gzipped as expected. The only problem is JSON is not getting gzipped and webpagetest.org complains. IIS has been restarted

My `MetaBase.xml` for both `IIsCompressionScheme` gzip and deflate

```
    HcFileExtensions="htm
        html
        asp
        txt
        css
        js
        php
        rdf
        xml
        ttf
        json"
```

Is this even possible on IIS6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Try this trick***

**Open C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config with notepad and change the httpCompression tag:**[image: Modify the administration.config file as you can seen in image]

Dynamic Content Compression feature require  for that

Comment: I go to "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv" and there is no folder called "config" nor can I find "administration.config" file. Mb that's because I have IIS 6?

Comment: follow this link, this may helpful for you. [link] (http://www.smallworkarounds.net/2009/01/aspnet-iis-tricks-using-gzip.html)

Comment: I followed all of this before. Everything is getting GZIPed except json

Comment: Ok it finally worked! So I was doing everything from that link. Except I was editing metabase.xml that was inside my web directory. Turns out I needed the one that is located in C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Metabase.xml

Comment: I'll give the bounty since it's going to expire anyway. )

Answer (score 0):

It have come to my attention that your frontend application must have this:

```
        headers : {
            "Content-Encoding" : "gzip"
        },
```

Enabled so it notifies the backend that gzip can be used.

FYI, if your JSON response is too small, gziping could actually make it slower. Just so you know.

Comment: Alexander- you can compress JSON response also.